# When did Hobbits come into being?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, hobbits

Elves were awoken during the Years of the Trees (Telperion & Laurelin) in Culvienen.

Men were awoken the first Year of the First Age in Hildorien

Dwarves were created and awoken somewhere east of the Blue mountains

At what time period did Hobbits appear and where did they come from?

Comment: Sometime after men, as a subspecies of men, I think...

Comment: One of his book, can't remember which, talked about the different Hobbit species that branched off. That would probably be the best source.

Comment: @suchiuomizu That question is how/what, not when. I think the answer will still be that is unkown however, as that letter says.

Comment: Hobbits are sub-species of Men. They were in existence at least by the end of the Second Age, and began migrating at the beginning of the Third Age. http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Hobbits